# SQL - how can I copy a column and its data to a new column in the same table?

Tags: sql

I know i want to use an update statement but im having trouble with the structure of the query

Comment: If you do not want to create a "new" column, change the question title to "another" column. New Column means you are going to create a column newly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first of the following 2 SQL statements will create the new column in the table, and the second, `update` statement will populate the new column from the old column.

```
alter table Table1 add newColumn char(32);
update table1 set newColumn=oldColumn;
commit;
```

Comment: having said that, if you are going to do this type of operation in a working program, there is something not correct in your program design. Columns and Tables must be designed ahead of the time following rules such as Normalization, and once the Schema is finalized, you will write the program.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table
SET column2 = column1
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a new column using an update, you have to do that first. Then it's just as simple as:

```
update TheTable set NewColumn = OldColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_name set column_to_be_changed = existing column
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!